# Updating Third Party Cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to see if I can edit a cookie of a third party's cookies (ultimately I want to override a zip code cookie) using PHP. While I am able to use setcookie to add a cookie in the default directory, I'm unable to use it to either add or edit an existing cookie. Below is an example of the cookie record in Firefox:

```
Name: nyt-recmod
Content: 1
Domain: .nytimes.com
Path: /
Send For: Any type of connection
Expires: Saturday, September 29, 2012 10:31:07 PM
```

and two lines of test code I am using to attempt to change it:

```
$rv = setcookie('nyt-recmod', '0', time()+3600,'/','.nytimes.com',0);  
$rv = setcookie('nyt-recmod', '0', time()+3600,'/','./nytimes.com',0);
```

What should I change in order to modify this cookie in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change other site's cookies through your website. It's quite incredibly insecure, for one thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read or set cookies for other domains. This is part of the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Also the browsers store the cookie in some different way. The bowser makes directories for each site and stores the cookies of that site in it's respective folder. So, as all the cookies are not in common place, your code would probably not find the cookie.

Atleast this is the case in firefox. Which you can check in **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Privacy** -> click on 'remove individual cookies'.